# Nested Regex matching in Java

Tags: java, regex, nested, pattern-matching

I have a scenario where I want to do a nested expression matching in Java.

Consider the following expression:

```
SUM_ALL(2:3,4:5)>20
```

where `SUM_ALL` has a reserved operator meaning in the application. Now, I want to extract the operator name and its arguments from a given expression. For doing the same, I have defined my pattern expression as follows:

```
Pattern testPattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z_]+)\\s*\\(\\s*([0-9:,]+)\\s*\\).*");
```

This works fine if the expression is limited simply to the above. Here is the output for the same:

```
Group 1: SUM_ALL
Group 2: 2:3,4:5
```

Now, in a given expression, I may not be aware of the number of such operators present. For example consider the following case:

```
SUM_ALL(4:5,6:7)>MAX(2:3,4:4)+MIN(3:4,5:7)
```

Now, I want to extract each of the above operators and their respective arguments to perform the calculation according to their reserved meaning and then evaluate a simple math expression.

If there were a nesting capability in the Java pattern matcher it would have helped to extract the operators one by one by considering the rest of the expression once an operator is resolved. I know it is possible to do it by capturing the rest of the expression in a separate group and then running the matcher on that group value and keep doing it until we reach the end of the expression, but I would be more interested to know if the pattern-matcher has an inherent functionality for the same.

Comment: When managing such formulae which can have free forms, you should start looking into lexers / parsers, like Parboiled or Javacc...

Comment: ... or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), a fine tool for parsing your own grammar

Comment: The absolute best resource to learn regex for Java (and Perl, .NET, PHP/PCRE, etc.) is of course the book: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "Best book on Regex - ever!") By Jeffrey Friedl. Hands down the most useful book I've ever read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like this:

```
String str = "SUM_ALL(4:5,6:7)>MAX(2:3,4:4)+MIN(3:4,5:7)";
Matcher m = 
    Pattern.compile("(?i).*?([a-z_]+)\\s*\\(\\s*([\\d:,]+)\\s*\\)").matcher(str);
while (m.find())
   System.out.printf("%s :: %s%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
SUM_ALL :: 4:5,6:7
MAX :: 2:3,4:4
MIN :: 3:4,5:7
```

Comment: Thanks for a wonderful answer. Can you please suggest some good sources to read on regex and parsing in java?

Comment: Java official doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ and this tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html are good starting points.

Answer (score 1):

Well, have this:

`(?:(SUM_ALL|MAX|MIN|addmorehere)\\(((?:\d+:\d+,?){2})\\)[+-><*/addmorehere]?)+`

It's not really scaped for java or any language but you get the idea